# PHP does not print anything in <> tags

Tags: php

PHP does not print anything between the `<>` tags.

For example following code will print: `Reply-To: Webmaster`. Is this something to do with the PHP configuration on my server?

```
$header = "Reply-To: Webmaster <noreply@example.com>\r\n";
echo $header;
```

Comment: No, this is simply your browser trying to interpret it as HTML … look at the HTML source code of the page, or apply `htmlspecialchars` to the value …

Comment: Because its treated as HTML. If you want to output readable `<>` tags, use `htmlspecialchars()` on the output where you print it (but not in the mail function!)

Comment: To see what exactly PHP printed to your page right click on page and go for "View page source" (or something similar, depending on browser you use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

You should escape your text to be rendered properly in the browser. You can use `htmlentities` for that:

```
$header = "Reply-To: Webmaster <noreply@example.com>\r\n";
echo htmlentities($header);
```